# Why doesn't <numeric> require/allow std::, but <cmath> does?

Tags: c++, std

Why, at least in my code, does `<numeric>` NOT require or ALLOW `std::`?

I'm following along with a YouTube SDL2 tutorial, and IntelliSense has squiggled all my trig functions. In the process of experimenting, I removed all the `std::` and it worked and compiled fine. I decided to add `#include <cmath>` as well and commented out `#include <numeric>`, and now all the math functions again have squiggles. I reinserted the `std::` and the squiggles disappeared.

I did some Google research and it seems to me that `<numeric>` is part of the standard library and thus should require `std::`.

```cpp
#include "screen.h"
#include <numeric>
//#include <cmath>

void line(Screen& screen, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float dx = x2 - x1;
    float dy = y2 - y1;

    float length = float (sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
    float angle = float (atan2(dy, dx));

    for (float i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        screen.pixel(
            x1 + float (cos(angle) * i),
            y1 + float (sin(angle) * i)
        );
    }
}

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    Screen screen;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        screen.pixel(rand() % 640, rand() % 480);
    }
    line(screen, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    while (true)
    {
        screen.show();
        screen.input();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OK, once again, the code is NOT mine, it's a YouTube tutorial, thus it's his code, and this code compiled using `<numeric>` only for math functions such as `sin()`, `cos()`, `atan2()` and `sqrt()`. My one modification was to include `<cmath>`.

Here's my reproducible example:

```
//#include "screen.h"
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>

void line( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float dx = x2 - x1;
    float dy = y2 - y1;

    float length = float (sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
    float angle = float (atan2(dy, dx));

    for (float i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {   
        float tempx1 = x1 + float(cos(angle) * i);
        float tempy1 = y1 + float(sin(angle) * i);
        std::cout << i << " " << x1 << " " << y1 << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    line(2, 2, 20, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: iirc `<cxxxx>` guarantee names under `std` namespace, while `<xxxx.h>` guarantee names under global space. your title seems mismatch the question body. (and c++ is case sensitive, don't type `STD::` it'd not work)

Comment: The [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric) and [`<cmath>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) headers have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: What does `"screen.h"` declares and what are you using from `<numeric>`?

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Generally speaking, STL includes can bring stuff that isn't promised by the standart.

Comment: Your code, as shown, is not using any functions from `<numeric>`.  If you were to use any of those function, you would find that use of `std` is required, since the functions ARE in namespace `std`.

Comment: Not only is nothing from `<numeric>` shown, but they're pulling in stuff like `rand()` without including the appropriate headers. It's like opposite day for includes. And `rand()` is used incorrectly to boot.

Comment: If I try to compile your "reproducible example" in GCC, it [fails as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/7cW66j1dd). If I take out `#include <numeric>` and put in `#include <cmath>`--the header that actually has the functions you're using--it works both with and without the `std::` prefix in GCC and MSVC. I haven't downvoted this question, but I suspect the people who have did so because there's a bunch of (apparently?) irrelevant code in here and the snippets that ostensibly demonstrate the issue do not do so for them.

Comment: It does [appear](https://godbolt.org/z/3ejxxcr1x) that MSVC pulls in a bunch of mathematical functions just from including `<iostream>`. In [both](https://godbolt.org/z/j4ePrPYWr) the `std` namespace and the global namespace. A bit surprising of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ header `<cmath>` declares exactly the same Standard C math functions also declared in the C header [`<math.h>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm), with functions like `pow()`, `ceil()`, `sqrt()`, `tan()`, and constants like `M_PI`.

The C++ header [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric) is completely different:

```
 Components for performing numeric operations. 
 Includes support for complex number types, random number generation,
 numeric (n-at-a-time) arrays, generalized numeric algorithms,
 and mathematical special functions.
```

If you happen to have some header named `numeric.h` on your workstation ... it's completely unrelated to either of the above headers.  For example:

```
Directory of c:\Ruby30-x64\include\ruby-3.0.0\ruby\internal\intern
  07/09/2021  07:38 PM             1,941 numeric.h
```

If you want to use the Standard C library math functions `sqrt()` or `cos()` (callable from either C or C++), then you need to `#include` either `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`.

None of the functions in `<math.h>` are in the C++ namespace `std`, hence they don't need to be qualified with `std::xxx`.

Comment: The #include <numeric> is what ever came with MSVS 22 community                                      // numeric standard header
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 WITH LLVM-exception

Comment: Q: Between the comments and my reply, do you understand distinction between cmath, math.h, numeric and numeric.h?  If not, exactly what don't you understand?  Q: Did we address your original question?  If not, exactly what is (are) your remaining question(s)?

Comment: While really appreciate you expounding on the distinction between cmath,math.h and numeric, that was not really my question. My original question was why numeric didn't require a std::, not which include was more appropriate.

Comment: @MichealDouble • what functions out of `<numeric>` are you using?

Comment: @Micheal Double- I updated my reply (and corrected a misstatement),  Look at the headers themselves (e.g. in "notepad").  Hopefully my update addresses your remaining questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct term for the `cxxxxx` headers is but I don't think it's "alias", since they're not 100% identical to the C version.

Comment: _"and constants like `M_PI`"_ - Neither standard C nor C++ requires `M_PI` to be defined in `math.h`/`cmath`.